# dplyr: summarize by group (sum) is extremely slow

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two datasets: `inds` (individuals) and `hhs` (households).

I'm trying to sum all `inds$income` grouped by `UID` (unique ID) and create a new column on `hhs` with the sum of the income of all individuals in a households. Some individuals don't have any income, in which case they have 'NA' for that variable. The code I'm using is:

```
hhs <- left_join(hhs, inds %>% group_by(UID) %>% summarize(hhincome = sum(income, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

However, it's extremely slow. `inds` has over 2 million rows, `hhs` has about 550k rows. I've used `dplyr` to average or count similar variables in the same datasets, and it usually takes ten seconds or less to get this done. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Is there any way to make it faster?

Edit: as I said, I've used `dplyer` to get mean household values without a problem with

```
hhs <- left_join(hhs, inds %>% filter(AGE > 2) %>% group_by(UID) %>% summarize(L_Bilingual = mean(Bilingual, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

It takes 5 seconds to calculate the means with the code above. Is there anything particular to the function `sum()` that makes it slower?

Comment: Is `UID` the only column name that `hhs` and `inds` have in common? How many rows do you expect to end up with in the joined data frame?

Comment: Yes. The joined dataframe will have 559473 rows.

Comment: I think what @eipi10 is getting at is there is no `by=` join criteria specified here. If you have multiple columns in common which have very few unique values, you could be getting a ridiculously large join.

Comment: UID = unique household ID.

Comment: I've used dplyr to get the average of certain columns with:
hhs <- left_join(hhs, inds %>% filter(AGE > 2) %>% group_by(UID) %>% summarize(Bilingual = mean(Bilingual, na.rm=TRUE)))

Comment: The code above only takes 5 seconds to calculate the 550k rows.

Comment: @Werner - The same issue with no `by=` variable might still apply. Can you try `left_join(hhs, inds %>% ..., by="UID")` and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: I moved group_by(income) to the end and got: Error: Column `UID` is unknown

Comment: I think what everyone in the comments is suggesting is that you need to specify the column you are joining by since `left_join` takes `letf_join(x, y, by = ...)`, hence,
`hhs <- left_join(hhs, inds %>% group_by(UID) %>% summarize(hhincome = sum(income, na.rm=TRUE)), by = "UID")`

Comment: @Croote just trying that, same thing. It's slow as well. it's been running for two minutes already and no result.

Comment: @Werner - since we don't have your data, we're all guessing. If specifying a `by=` doesn't solve it then you probably have duplication of `UID` values in your original `hhs` file. Try `length(unique(hhs$UID))` and make sure it's the same as `nrow(hhs)` . If it's not, you potentially have an issue.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was, thanks a lot for your help everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the fake data below, the summarize-and-join takes about 2 seconds on my machine, which is a new Macbook Pro. Even with a slower machine, it shouldn't take longer than maybe 10 or 15 seconds. Is it possible that the join is creating many more rows than you think? If you provide more details about the structure of your data, we can be more specific about what might be going wrong.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)

# Generate two data frames with only the UID column in common
set.seed(2)
hhs = data.frame(UID=1:550000, replicate(30, runif(550000))) %>% 
  set_names(c("UID", paste0("V",1:30)))
inds = data.frame(UID=sample(1:550000, 2e6, replace=TRUE), 
                  income=rnorm(2e6, 5e4, 1e4),
                  replicate(20, rnorm(2e6, 5e4, 1e4)))

microbenchmark(join=left_join(hhs, inds %>% group_by(UID) %>% 
                                summarize(hhincome = sum(income, na.rm=TRUE))),
               times=5)
```

> ```
> Unit: seconds
>  expr      min       lq     mean median       uq      max neval
>  join 1.924749 1.988773 2.722018 2.0063 2.068044 5.622223     5
> ```

Comment: It's slow as well, so it's probably something with the structure of my data. Unfortunately I can't share the data (it's too big), so let me see if I figure it out what the problem is. Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Man, I think I figured it out. the inds$income had labels. It got faster after I removed them !

Answer (score 4):

Here's what was making it slow: I hadn't realized that `inds$income` had labels:

```
> head(inds$income)
<Labelled double>: Earned income
[1]      0      0      0      0 258000      0

Labels:
value                  label
 99999998       Unknown/missing.
 99999999 NIU (not in universe).
```

Problem was fixed when I removed the labels (recoding the column with `as.numeric()`).

Comment: I did the same.  I created a variable using Difftime, and I forgot to change the new variable to as.numeric.  Thank You!

Comment: Converting difftime variables to numeric has sped up group_by() and summarise() for me in the past too.