# dplyr::summarize by group (sum) is extremely slow (due to NAs ?)

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I am trying to collapse different rows into a single one as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  Geography = c("Austria", "Austria", "Austria"),
  Subcategory = c("Dishwashers", "Dishwashers", "Dishwashers"),
  LBN = c("OK", "Koenig", "Other"),
  NBO = c("Media-Saturn Beteiligungs GesmbH", "Media-Saturn Beteiligungs GesmbH", "Other"),
  GBO_BI = c(5.3, 3.2, 4),
  Sh_2012 = c(5.3, 3.2, 4)
)

# create the second tibble
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Geography, Subcategory, NBO) %>%
  summarize(
    LBN = paste(LBN, collapse = ","),
    GBO_BI = sum(GBO_BI, na.rm = TRUE),
    Sh_2012 = sum(Sh_2012, na.rm = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Problem: when I run the latter script on R, with the real data, it takes an unbearable amount of time (after 20 minutes, still no result...) to produce an output.

The main differece from the example above are that I have Sh_2012 to Sh_2021 (these columns are called "Share_2012" to "Share_2021" in the real dataset), and I am repeating this also for another variable, called Unit_2012 to Unit_2021, plus I have two additional grouping variables, which are `GBO_BI` and `Data_Type`). Hereunder the structure of the data: `df` is called `renamed_pl`, `df_2` is called `summarized_pl`

```
str(renamed_pl)

tibble [485,372 x 34] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Geography           : chr [1:485372] "Austria" "Austria" "Austria" "Austria" ...
 $ Industry            : chr [1:485372] "Consumer Appliances" "Consumer Appliances" "Consumer Appliances" "Consumer Appliances" ...
 $ Category            : chr [1:485372] "Major Appliances" "Major Appliances" "Major Appliances" "Major Appliances" ...
 $ Subcategory         : chr [1:485372] "Major Appliances" "Major Appliances" "Major Appliances" "Major Appliances" ...
 $ NACE_mapping        : chr [1:485372] "C27.51, C27.52" "C27.51, C27.52" "C27.51, C27.52" "C27.51, C27.52" ...
 $ Hierarchy_level     : num [1:485372] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Data_Type           : chr [1:485372] "Retail Volume" "Retail Volume" "Retail Volume" "Retail Volume" ...
 $ Local_Brand_Name    : chr [1:485372] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Global_Brand_Name   : chr [1:485372] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ National_Brand_Owner: chr [1:485372] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ GBO_BI              : chr [1:485372] "Total" "BSH Hausgeräte GmbH" "Others" "Whirlpool Corp" ...
 $ Share_2012          : num [1:485372] 100 NA 18.19 6.27 9.5 ...
 $ Share_2013          : num [1:485372] 100 NA 17.86 6.13 9.92 ...
 $ Share_2014          : num [1:485372] 100 NA 16.6 13.8 10.2 ...
 $ Share_2015          : num [1:485372] 100 24.5 17.5 13.7 10.3 ...
 $ Share_2016          : num [1:485372] 100 24.6 18.9 13.5 10.7 ...
 $ Share_2017          : num [1:485372] 100 24.8 19.3 13.4 11 ...
 $ Share_2018          : num [1:485372] 100 24.9 19.4 13.3 11.1 ...
 $ Share_2019          : num [1:485372] 100 25.1 19.1 13.1 11.2 ...
 $ Share_2020          : num [1:485372] 100 25.2 19.4 12.9 11.3 ...
 $ Share_2021          : num [1:485372] 100 25.4 18.8 12.9 11.4 ...
 $ Current_Constant    : chr [1:485372] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Currency_Conversion : chr [1:485372] "Volume" "Volume" "Volume" "Volume" ...
 $ Measure             : chr [1:485372] "000 units" "000 units" "000 units" "000 units" ...
 $ Unit_2012           : num [1:485372] 1605 NA 292 101 153 ...
 $ Unit_2013           : num [1:485372] 1657 NA 296 102 164 ...
 $ Unit_2014           : num [1:485372] 1699 NA 282 235 174 ...
 $ Unit_2015           : num [1:485372] 1769 434 310 243 182 ...
 $ Unit_2016           : num [1:485372] 1838 452 348 248 196 ...
 $ Unit_2017           : num [1:485372] 1893 469 366 255 207 ...
 $ Unit_2018           : num [1:485372] 1928 480 374 257 214 ...
 $ Unit_2019           : num [1:485372] 1952 490 372 257 219 ...
 $ Unit_2020           : num [1:485372] 2035 512 396 262 231 ...
 $ Unit_2021           : num [1:485372] 2008 509 379 260 229 ...
```

Hereunder the real script: note that I rename the columns `Local_Brand_Name`, `National_Brand_Owner` and I get rid of `Global_Brand_Name`

```
summarized_pl <- renamed_pl %>%
 rename(LBN = Local_Brand_Name,
         NBO = National_Brand_Owner,
         ) %>%
  select(-Global_Brand_Name) %>%
  group_by(Geography, Subcategory, Data_Type,
           GBO_BI, NBO) %>%
  summarize(LBN = paste(unique(LBN), collapse = ","),
           across(starts_with("Share_"), sum, na.rm = TRUE),
           across(starts_with("Unit_"), sum, na.rm = TRUE)
           )
```

Additional info: the columns `LBN` and `NBO` are plenty of missing values: out of 485,372 observations, 474,241
are missing, and I suspect this is the main cause of the problem.

I tried with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55717649/dplyr-summarize-by-group-sum-is-extremely-slow), but it did not help, I don't have labels in my columns...

Comment: How many groups you have?   If dplyr is slow, try with` dat.atable` i.e. `library(data.table);setDT(renamed_pl)[, .(GBO_BI = sum(GBO_BI, na.rm = TRUE),
    Sh_2012 = sum(Sh_2012, na.rm = TRUE)), .(Geography, Subcategory, NBO)]`

Comment: I have: 35 `Geography` (countries), 13 `Data_Type` , 661 `Subcategory`, 895 `LBN`,  `25000` about `GBO_BI`, and 403 `NBO`. Ok, I see the problem, but maybe I found the solution as well: in reality, I need to perform `summarize` only if `GBO_BI == "Private Label"`

Comment: In that case, do a `filter` before the grouping

Comment: No I can't `filter`, I need `ifelse` or something similar